# Arduino AES encryption, working example or tutorial

Tags: communication

I am quite new to idea of encryption and am trying to use aes-256-ecb encryption. 
 I am using library called "Arduino cryptography". Unfortunately I could not find any tutorial that would explain how to encrypt a json string (and other things latter) using a  key.
I have a function that generates same key on both sides of Arduino and php script on a server side, but I could not find a working tutorial (except the case of obsolete buggy library with instruction like : "copy this text" and even that doesn't work.
Unfortunately libraries examples do not bother to show how to retrieve  encrypted string or explain what is what and instead just focus on checking how long encryption takes. 
Does any of you know of some tutorial or an example from which I could engineer a solution?
library link:[The library](https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/index.html)
in buioltin example there is a code of:

```
cipher->decryptBlock(buffer, test->ciphertext);
```

But I do not understand where is the output and where the input here

Second  question would be if I can use other modes like the mentioned GCM simply by changing the value in

```
static TestVector const testVectorAES256 = {
    .name        = "AES-256-ECB",
    .key         = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
                    0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F,
                    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
                    0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F},
    .plaintext   = {0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77,
                    0x88, 0x99, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF},
    .ciphertext  = {0x8E, 0xA2, 0xB7, 0xCA, 0x51, 0x67, 0x45, 0xBF,
                    0xEA, 0xFC, 0x49, 0x90, 0x4B, 0x49, 0x60, 0x89}
};
```

or how?

After bits and strougles I have managed to get this working, but next step is how to make it take a string:

```
/*Skúška kódovania GCM-AES256#*/

#include <Crypto.h>
#include <AES.h>
#include <GCM.h>
//#include <pgmspace.h>

struct TestVector
{
    const char *name;
    uint8_t key[32];
    uint8_t plaintext[60];
    uint8_t ciphertext[60];
    uint8_t authdata[20];
    uint8_t iv[12];
    uint8_t tag[16];
    size_t authsize;
    size_t datasize;
    size_t tagsize;
    size_t ivsize;
};

static TestVector const testVectorGCM PROGMEM = {
    .name        = "AES-256 GCM",
    .key         = {0xfe, 0xff, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x86, 0x65, 0x73, 0x1c,
                    0x6d, 0x6a, 0x8f, 0x94, 0x67, 0x30, 0x83, 0x08,
                    0xfe, 0xff, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x86, 0x65, 0x73, 0x1c,
                    0x6d, 0x6a, 0x8f, 0x94, 0x67, 0x30, 0x83, 0x08},
    .plaintext   = {0xd9, 0x31, 0x32, 0x25, 0xf8, 0x84, 0x06, 0xe5,
                    0xa5, 0x59, 0x09, 0xc5, 0xaf, 0xf5, 0x26, 0x9a,
                    0x86, 0xa7, 0xa9, 0x53, 0x15, 0x34, 0xf7, 0xda,
                    0x2e, 0x4c, 0x30, 0x3d, 0x8a, 0x31, 0x8a, 0x72,
                    0x1c, 0x3c, 0x0c, 0x95, 0x95, 0x68, 0x09, 0x53,
                    0x2f, 0xcf, 0x0e, 0x24, 0x49, 0xa6, 0xb5, 0x25,
                    0xb1, 0x6a, 0xed, 0xf5, 0xaa, 0x0d, 0xe6, 0x57,
                    0xba, 0x63, 0x7b, 0x39},
    .ciphertext  = {0x52, 0x2d, 0xc1, 0xf0, 0x99, 0x56, 0x7d, 0x07,
                    0xf4, 0x7f, 0x37, 0xa3, 0x2a, 0x84, 0x42, 0x7d,
                    0x64, 0x3a, 0x8c, 0xdc, 0xbf, 0xe5, 0xc0, 0xc9,
                    0x75, 0x98, 0xa2, 0xbd, 0x25, 0x55, 0xd1, 0xaa,
                    0x8c, 0xb0, 0x8e, 0x48, 0x59, 0x0d, 0xbb, 0x3d,
                    0xa7, 0xb0, 0x8b, 0x10, 0x56, 0x82, 0x88, 0x38,
                    0xc5, 0xf6, 0x1e, 0x63, 0x93, 0xba, 0x7a, 0x0a,
                    0xbc, 0xc9, 0xf6, 0x62},
    .authdata    = {0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
                    0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
                    0xab, 0xad, 0xda, 0xd2},
    .iv          = {0xca, 0xfe, 0xba, 0xbe, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xdb, 0xad,
                    0xde, 0xca, 0xf8, 0x88},
    .tag         = {0x76, 0xfc, 0x6e, 0xce, 0x0f, 0x4e, 0x17, 0x68,
                    0xcd, 0xdf, 0x88, 0x53, 0xbb, 0x2d, 0x55, 0x1b},
    .authsize    = 20,
    .datasize    = 60,
    .tagsize     = 16,
    .ivsize      = 12
};

TestVector testVector;
byte buffer[128];

bool testCipher_N(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, size_t inc)
{
    size_t posn, len;
    uint8_t tag[16];

    crypto_feed_watchdog();

    cipher->clear();
    if (!cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize())) {
        Serial.print("setKey ");
        return false;
    }
    if (!cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize)) {
        Serial.print("setIV ");
        return false;
    }

    memset(buffer, 0xBA, sizeof(buffer));

    for (posn = 0; posn < test->authsize; posn += inc) {
        len = test->authsize - posn;
        if (len > inc)
            len = inc;
        cipher->addAuthData(test->authdata + posn, len);
    }

    for (posn = 0; posn < test->datasize; posn += inc) {
        len = test->datasize - posn;
        if (len > inc)
            len = inc;
        cipher->encrypt(buffer + posn, test->plaintext + posn, len);
    }


    Serial.println("Vystup:\n");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++) printf("0x%X,",buffer[i]);

    return true;
}

void testCipher(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test)
{
    bool ok;

    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));
    test = &testVector;

    Serial.print(test->name);
    Serial.print(" ... ");

    ok  = testCipher_N(cipher, test, test->datasize);
    /*ok &= testCipher_N(cipher, test, 1);
    ok &= testCipher_N(cipher, test, 2);
    ok &= testCipher_N(cipher, test, 5);
    ok &= testCipher_N(cipher, test, 8);
    ok &= testCipher_N(cipher, test, 13);
    ok &= testCipher_N(cipher, test, 16);*/

    if (ok)
        Serial.println("Passed");
    else
        Serial.println("Failed");
}

void perfCipherSetKey(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, const char *name)
{
    unsigned long start;
    unsigned long elapsed;
    int count;

    crypto_feed_watchdog();

    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));
    test = &testVector;

    Serial.print(name);
    Serial.print(" SetKey ... ");

    start = micros();
    for (count = 0; count < 1000; ++count) {
        cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize());
        cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize);
    }
    elapsed = micros() - start;

    Serial.print(elapsed / 1000.0);
    Serial.print("us per operation, ");
    Serial.print((1000.0 * 1000000.0) / elapsed);
    Serial.println(" per second");
}

void perfCipherEncrypt(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, const char *name)
{
    unsigned long start;
    unsigned long elapsed;
    int count;

    crypto_feed_watchdog();

    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));
    test = &testVector;

    Serial.print(name);
    Serial.print(" Encrypt ... ");

    cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize());
    cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize);
    start = micros();
    for (count = 0; count < 500; ++count) {
        cipher->encrypt(buffer, buffer, 128);
    }
    elapsed = micros() - start;

    Serial.print(elapsed / (128.0 * 500.0));
    Serial.print("us per byte, ");
    Serial.print((128.0 * 500.0 * 1000000.0) / elapsed);
    Serial.println(" bytes per second");
}


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Začínam\n");
    GCM <AES256> *gcm=0;
    gcm= new GCM<AES256>();
    gcm->setKey(testVectorGCM.key, 32);
    gcm->setIV(testVectorGCM.iv,testVectorGCM.ivsize);
    crypto_feed_watchdog();
    //gcm->encrypt(buffer,testVectorGCM.plaintext,60);
    testCipher(gcm,&testVectorGCM);
    delete gcm;
    //gcm.encrypt(&vstupny,&vystup,49);
    crypto_feed_watchdog();
    Serial.println("Vystup: \n");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<50;i++) Serial.print(buffer[i]);
}

void loop(){
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
}
```

I need to be able to get the text on PHP side

Comment: It is not recommended to use ECB mode. GCM is currently state of art.

Comment: install the library using your Arduino IDE, then look at the examples ... some of them show encrypt and decrypt functions ..... or look at the examples online https://github.com/OperatorFoundation/Crypto .... that link is found in the `library.json` file

Comment: your avatar is ironic, considering the [textbook image used to show why ECB sucks](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Tux_ecb.jpg).

Comment: @Kwasmich and dandavis I take your Point

Comment: @jsotola I have seen them, but I still do not understand them where the output comes and what is what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of an answer. After the advise from @Kwasmich I have converted to aes-256-gcm.
Upgraded to UTF-8 thanks to Edgar Bonet


Based mostly on GCMTest example comming with Arduino Cryptograhy libraries:
-----------------------------------------------
**Shared between Encryption and decrition**
First need to define parts which will not change:

```
#include <Crypto.h>
#include <AES.h>
#include <GCM.h>


struct TestVector
{
    const char *name;
    uint8_t key[32];
    uint8_t authdata[20];
    uint8_t iv[12];
    uint8_t tag[16];
    size_t authsize;
    size_t tagsize;
    size_t ivsize;
};

static TestVector const testVectorGCM PROGMEM = {   //Dont forget to change the Values here
    .name        = "AES-256 GCM",
    .key         = {0xfe, 0xff, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x86, 0x65, 0x73, 0x1c,
                    0x6d, 0x6a, 0x8f, 0x94, 0x67, 0x30, 0x83, 0x08,
                    0xfe, 0xff, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x86, 0x65, 0x73, 0x1c,
                    0x6d, 0x6a, 0x8f, 0x94, 0x67, 0x30, 0x83, 0x08},
    .authdata    = {0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
                    0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
                    0xab, 0xad, 0xda, 0xd2},
    .iv          = {0xca, 0xfe, 0xba, 0xbe, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xdb, 0xad,
                    0xde, 0xca, 0xf8, 0x88},
    .tag         = {0x76, 0xfc, 0x6e, 0xce, 0x0f, 0x4e, 0x17, 0x68,
                    0xcd, 0xdf, 0x88, 0x53, 0xbb, 0x2d, 0x55, 0x1b},
    .authsize    = 20,
    .tagsize     = 16,
    .ivsize      = 12
};
```

Now create a global buffer (easier to understand then pointers)

```
TestVector testVector;
byte buffer[128];
```

**Encrytpion**

```
{
    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));   //Load into memory
    test = &testVector;
    size_t posn, len;
    uint8_t tag[16];
    crypto_feed_watchdog();    //To protect from Watchdog reseting this function
```

It is important to clear memory of any ciphering before doing one:

```
    cipher->clear();
```

```
    cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize());    //Setting key
    cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize);     //vector
    for (posn = 0; posn < test->authsize; posn += datasize) {
        len = test->authsize - posn;
        if (len > datasize)
            len = datasize;
        cipher->addAuthData(test->authdata + posn, len);   //To make hack even more confusing
    }
    Serial.print("input numbers ");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<60; i++) Serial.printf("%X",buffer[i]);
    Serial.println();

    for (posn = 0; posn < datasize; posn += datasize) {
        len = datasize - posn;
        if (len > datasize) len = datasize;
        crypto_feed_watchdog();
        cipher->encrypt((uint8_t*)buffer + posn, buffer + posn, len); //This is why we are here
        crypto_feed_watchdog();
    }
    Serial.println("Vystup:\n");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++) printf("0x%X,",buffer[i]);
}
```

**Decryption**

```
void decrypt(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, size_t datasize){
    bool ok;

    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));
    test = &testVector;
    size_t posn, len;
    uint8_t tag[16];
    crypto_feed_watchdog();
    cipher->clear();
    cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize());
    cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize);
    for (posn = 0; posn < test->authsize; posn += datasize) {
        len = test->authsize - posn;
        if (len > datasize)
            len = datasize;
        cipher->addAuthData(test->authdata + posn, len);
    }

    for (posn = 0; posn < datasize; posn += datasize) {
        len = datasize - posn;
        if (len > datasize)
            len = datasize;
        cipher->decrypt((uint8_t*)buffer + posn, buffer + posn, len);
    }

    Serial.print("\nVystup: ");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<60;i++) Serial.printf("%c",(char)buffer[i]);
    Serial.println();

}
```

-----------------------------------------------
full example:

```
/*Skúška kódovania GCM-AES256#*/

#include <Crypto.h>
#include <AES.h>
#include <GCM.h>

struct TestVector
{
    const char *name;
    uint8_t key[32];
    uint8_t authdata[20];
    uint8_t iv[12];
    uint8_t tag[16];
    size_t authsize;
    size_t tagsize;
    size_t ivsize;
};

static TestVector const testVectorGCM PROGMEM = {
    .name        = "AES-256 GCM",
    .key         = {0xfe, 0xff, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x86, 0x65, 0x73, 0x1c,
                    0x6d, 0x6a, 0x8f, 0x94, 0x67, 0x30, 0x83, 0x08,
                    0xfe, 0xff, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x86, 0x65, 0x73, 0x1c,
                    0x6d, 0x6a, 0x8f, 0x94, 0x67, 0x30, 0x83, 0x08},
    .authdata    = {0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
                    0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef,
                    0xab, 0xad, 0xda, 0xd2},
    .iv          = {0xca, 0xfe, 0xba, 0xbe, 0xfa, 0xce, 0xdb, 0xad,
                    0xde, 0xca, 0xf8, 0x88},
    .tag         = {0x76, 0xfc, 0x6e, 0xce, 0x0f, 0x4e, 0x17, 0x68,
                    0xcd, 0xdf, 0x88, 0x53, 0xbb, 0x2d, 0x55, 0x1b},
    .authsize    = 20,
    .tagsize     = 16,
    .ivsize      = 12
};

TestVector testVector;
byte buffer[128];

void encrypt(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, size_t datasize)
{
    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));
    test = &testVector;
    size_t posn, len;
    uint8_t tag[16];
    crypto_feed_watchdog();

    cipher->clear();
    cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize());
    cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize);
    for (posn = 0; posn < test->authsize; posn += datasize) {
        len = test->authsize - posn;
        if (len > datasize)
            len = datasize;
        cipher->addAuthData(test->authdata + posn, len);
    }
    Serial.print("Cisla: ");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<60; i++) Serial.printf("%X",buffer[i]);
    Serial.println();

    for (posn = 0; posn < datasize; posn += datasize) {
        len = datasize - posn;
        if (len > datasize) len = datasize;
        crypto_feed_watchdog();
        cipher->encrypt((uint8_t*)buffer + posn, buffer + posn, len);
        crypto_feed_watchdog();
    }
    Serial.println("Vystup:\n");
    //      Decrypt
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++) printf("0x%X,",buffer[i]);
}

void decrypt(AuthenticatedCipher *cipher, const struct TestVector *test, size_t datasize){
    bool ok;

    memcpy_P(&testVector, test, sizeof(TestVector));
    test = &testVector;
    size_t posn, len;
    uint8_t tag[16];
    crypto_feed_watchdog();
    cipher->clear();
    cipher->setKey(test->key, cipher->keySize());
    cipher->setIV(test->iv, test->ivsize);
    for (posn = 0; posn < test->authsize; posn += datasize) {
        len = test->authsize - posn;
        if (len > datasize)
            len = datasize;
        cipher->addAuthData(test->authdata + posn, len);
    }

    for (posn = 0; posn < datasize; posn += datasize) {
        len = datasize - posn;
        if (len > datasize)
            len = datasize;
        cipher->decrypt((uint8_t*)buffer + posn, buffer + posn, len);
    }

    Serial.print("\nVystup: ");
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<60;i++) Serial.printf("%c",(char)buffer[i]);
    Serial.println();

}


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Začínam\n");
    GCM <AES256> *gcm=0;
    gcm= new GCM<AES256>();
    gcm->setKey(testVectorGCM.key, 32);
    gcm->setIV(testVectorGCM.iv,testVectorGCM.ivsize);
    crypto_feed_watchdog();
    memset(buffer, (int)'\0', sizeof(buffer));
    char vstup[30]="Tak to netuším";     //String containing Non-Asci characters
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<30; i++) buffer[i]=vstup[i]; 
    encrypt(gcm,&testVectorGCM,30);
    decrypt(gcm,&testVectorGCM,30);
    delete gcm;
}

void loop(){
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
}
```

simple key generator in PHP:

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<31;$i++) printf("0x%X,",random_int(0,0xFF));
printf("0x%X\n",random_int(0,0xFF));
?>
```

Comment: Re “_I could not figure-out how to convert utf-8 into numbers_”: an UTF-8 text _is_ a sequence of 8-bit numbers. There is nothing to convert.

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is that when one (char)letter get translated to multiple numbers (uint8_t), then converting it back require more then one conversion per number: needs to know how many numbers apply now and as such I could not convert numbers back to char letters

Comment: the important part is "and back" as while I could decrypt to the same int array I could not convert the int array into char array with utf-8 letters.

Comment: A `char` is not a letter (or a character): it's a byte. It synonym of `int8_t` and differs from `uint8_t` only by signedness. UTF-8 encodes each character as a sequence of 8-bit “code units”, thus an UTF-8 encoded text is just a byte array. You don't care about having a variable-width encoding unless you are converting to/from some form of wide characters. You can encrypt and decrypt the text with the same ease as ASCII text. If it happens to be stored as an array of `char`, you encrypt it with `cipher->encrypt((uint8_t*)buffer...)` and recover it with `cipher->decrypt((uint8_t*)buffer...)`.

Comment: What are the `authdata`, `iv` and `tag` parameters for? And should I change them too?

Comment: I will start with tag witch is something like a check When Decrypting. (think of it same as a checksum), SO it is send with the data from server to client
IV and Auth data are handy way to to make same input generate different output even with the same key. the benefits it has against the brute force attack alone are enormous (there are many others) I generate authdata each time on both sides under same algoritm and send the IV from client. Un

Comment: at early stages you can keep auth as constant. (create your own),
same as in case of IV (but this was first one of the two I have generated)

Comment: @Tomas Can you show an example of how you decrypt this with php?

Comment: Mine decryption routine is too complicated, but I have been using php-aes-gcm composer plugin from spomky-labs, which does contain examples.
https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/php-aes-gcm

Comment: you will find a composer in your main hosting panel from any competent  webhosting company, if like me you are using less competent webhosting for developement (planethippo) and more competent for deployment, then you might have to either get a lamp and install composer there or just copy the composer directories from better managed server. 
As a warning that when you are converting key, auth and tag from C++ approach to php approach, make sure the variable uses it always as string and that you use each number with two digits (without leading 0x).

Comment: Using your arduino sketch then feeding the params into ```openssl_decrypt``` (with ```hex2bin()```), or that lib, does not produce any result. I'm sure you'd help the community if you'd make a tutorial/video about the whole cycle (encrypt/decrypt on the arduino then encrypt/decrypt on the web server) as there are absolutely zero meaningfull practical examples on the internet.

Comment: I am disgraphic myself, so major tutorial in written form even about how to butter a bread is out of mine league.
Next weak I have inspector inspection (mine inspecting is inspected), so Ill do a video tutorial in two weeks time.  I have wanted to start youtube channel for a while, but mine last attempt died when lorry drow (i know its driven, but it sounds like there should be a past perfect short for being driven) over mine phone just after filming... Sorry, cant do it sooner as I want Rob W to pass me...